# Can the default login form of Spring Security be used i conjunction with JWT?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have created a REST API back-end that authenticates and authorizes the users via JWT. I also did add to my application the ability to register the user via email. So during registration I created a link that is sent to the user and when he click on it, he is redirected to a web page where he is informed that his account has been activated. What I want to do now is to incorporate the default spring security login form in order to protect the confirmation link from people that might have received the email by mistake. So, whenever he want to access this link he needs to login first.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.png",
                    "/**/*.gif",
                    "/**/*.svg",
                    "/**/*.jpg",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js"
            )
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(SIGN_UP_URLS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(H2_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

  }
```

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work? Any error message, any log message any response?

Comment: What I want to do and that I don't know if it can be done is that I want to secure the link I send to the user for registration. I want him to login via yhe default spring security form. At the moment if I don't secure it I will get a forbidden response because I use JWT. So how can I configure my application to work with both JWT and default spring security.

Comment: First, you should add form login to your configuration. Maybe that is enough? Did you try it?